# Django Получить данные из другой модели Foreignkey

Tags: django-model, jinja2

Помогите понять, как подцепить данные **rgb_name** из модели **rgb**, сейчас получаю только **rgb_numb**

**models.py**

```
class Rgb(models.Model):
    rgb_numb = models.CharField('Номер', max_length=10)
    rgb_name = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length=500)
    rgb_mod = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rgb_numb
  
class Reestr_db(models.Model):
    id_numb = models.CharField('Номер протокола', max_length=10, blank=True)
    rgb_numb = models.ForeignKey(rgb, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="result_rgb_numb", verbose_name="Номер")
    rgb_name = models.ForeignKey(rgb, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="result_rgb_name", verbose_name="Наименование")
```

**views.py**

```
def reestr(request):
    bazar = rgb.objects.all()
    baza = reestr_db.objects.order_by('id_numb')
    datar = {
        'baza': baza,
        'bazar': bazar
    }
    return render(request, 'main/reestr.html', datar)
```

**reestr.html**

```
  {% for el in baza %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ el.result_rgb_numb.rgb_mod }}</td>
            <td>{{ el.result_rgb_name.rgb_name }}</td>
```

Comment: Во-первых, названия классов пишутся в CamelCase; во-вторых, у вас, на мой взгляд, неправильно настроены отношения между моделями. Опишите, пожалуйста, как это должно быть.

Comment: А что такое `rgb_mod`? В таблице `rgb`  такого поля нет

Comment: @Dmitry таблица reestr_db это общая таблица с данными, в таблице rgb хранятся данные которые могут быть использованы в общей таблицы много раз. поэтому связь один к многим

Comment: @Vlados исправил

Comment: Данные в полях таблице есть?

Comment: @Vlados да, есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы планировали сделать нечто подобное:

```
class RGB(models.Model):
    rgb_numb = models.CharField('Номер', max_length=10)
    rgb_name = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length=500)
    rgb_mod = models.CharField('Наименование', max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rgb_numb
  
class ReestrDB(models.Model):
    id_numb = models.CharField('Номер протокола', max_length=10, blank=True)
    rgb = models.ForeignKey(
        rgb, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="result_rgb",
        verbose_name="Номер")
```

И затем в шаблоне:

```
  {% for el in baza %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ el.rgb.rgb_mod }}</td>
            <td>{{ el.rgb.rgb_name }}</td>
```

Comment: спасибо, попробовав ваш вариант понял наконец, в чём было дело)